# What code can I use to make a video/animation/soundclip to play after a certain time on my website? Can Javascript do this in particular?

Tags: javascript, html, video, project, dreamweaver

I am doing a college project whereby I have to create a website in Dreamweaver and I have to include timeline-based events on the different pages. For this I want it so when the page loads a video, for example, will play 5 seconds after followed by a sound clip.

Is there anything in Dreamweaver that will enable this? Or code in Javascript? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you've got so far, along with what errors you're getting.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

try this as example